Why minutes of latitude tick marks point up and and those of longitude point left

As you can see , the minute tick marks point up and left. Why is this?

I cannot see. Could you annotate your image so we're sure we're looking at the same thing?

Why did they pick a convention of "up" and "left" instead of some other convention? Is that what's being asked?

It may have to do with how our visual perception has been conditioned.  For example, page 11 of the chart users guide for mountain shadows says this: "Shaded relief shows how terrain may appear from the air. Shadows are shown as if light is coming from the northwest, because studies have shown that our visual perception has been conditioned to this view."

@RalphJ Yes that is the question.

Try changing your question title to, "Why minutes of latitude tick marks point up and and those of longitude point left ..." Otherwise your question reads as though they are pointing northwest. It took me some time to understand your question.

That chart is western hemisphere and north of the equator, right?  South of the equator and in the eastern hemisphere you'll see them in the other direction - this is helpful near the boundaries where the numeric values are similar (±0° or ±180°).

These lines are called the graticule. Sectional charts are equivalent of ICAO 1:500,000 VFR charts.
ICAO convention
For ICAO, ticks are defined in Annex 4 to the Chicago convention:

16.5.3 The graduation marks at 1' and 5' intervals shall extend away from the Greenwich Meridian and from the Equator.
Each 10' interval shall be shown by a mark on both sides of the graticule line.

For ICAO, the location of the 1' and 5' ticks varies with the lat/lon quadrant. For a location in the SE quadrant, away means bottom and right. E.g. this ICAO VFR chart for Cairns area in Australia, by 19°30'S, 146°30'W:

Source: Airservices Australia
That also works in the NE quadrant, e.g. for an ICAO VFR chart of France, away is top and right. But France has a small part of Brittany extending to the other side of the reference meridian (NW quadrant). This extension still uses the NE quadrant convention for some reason, which might be practical.
US sectional charts
US sectional charts are the equivalent of ICAO 1:500,000, but don't particularly follow ICAO conventions. Differences between local rules and ICAO recommendations are listed, ordered by annex number, in the US AIP at section GEN 1.7. There are many differences for Annex 4, but not for paragraph 16.5.3 (§16.5.3.1 has differences, but it is related to the size of the ticks, not their placement). So the US sectional charts follow the placement rule ("away") recommended by ICAO. CONUS area is in the NW quadrant, away means top and left.

However I suspect this placement is consistent with ICAO by chance. This allows for the ticks to appear on the white background at the top-left corner when a line is coincident with the corner coordinates:

The alternate choice would put the ticks on the white background at the bottom and on the right side, which is less natural.

So its more of a chart design trick as opposed to an actual useful purpose?

@Boeing787: Yes, a choice had to be made.

@Boeing787, no, it's not a "trick", it serves an "actual useful purpose" by reminding you what hemisphere you are in!

I mean, even if it had no specific use, it's just a standard.  Standards are often arbitrary because you need to have some consistent way to do things no matter what that way is.
